# writing dataframe to parquet files failes with empty or nested empty schemas

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I 'm pretty new to  both scala and spark. I have a very dumb question. I have a dataframe that I created from elasticsearch. I'm trying to write that s3 in parquet format. below is my code block and error i'm seeing. Can a good samaritan please undumb me on this one?

```
      val dfSchema = dataFrame.schema.json
//      log.info(dfSchema)
      dataFrame
        .withColumn("lastFound", functions.date_add(dataFrame.col("last_found"), -457))
        .write
        .partitionBy("lastFound")
        .mode("append")
        .format("parquet")
        .option("schema", dfSchema)
        .save("/tmp/elasticsearch/")
```

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
Datasource does not support writing empty or nested empty schemas.
Please make sure the data schema has at least one or more column(s).
         ;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$validateSchema(DataSource.scala:733)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWriting(DataSource.scala:523)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put schema when you write data in parquet format.

When you use the append mode, you suppose that you have already data stored in the path you precise and that you want to add new data. If you want to overwrite, you can put "overwrite" instead of "append" and if the path is new you don't need to put anything.

When you write to s3, the path normally should be like this "s3://bucket/the folder"

Can you try this :

```
 dataFrame
    .withColumn("lastFound", functions.date_add(dataFrame.col("last_found"), -457))
    .write
    .partitionBy("lastFound")
    .mode("append")
    .parquet("/tmp/elasticsearch/")
```

Comment: try overwrite instead of append. may be the schema between the data is different or put a different path

Comment: is there a way i can provide schema to the `.write`?

Comment: you can test and see the schema of your dataframe by df.printSchema().
try changing the output path

Comment: I got the entire schema printed. what am I looking for in there? It is only metadata. I can see the column I'm looking for in there. it is `nullable = true`

Comment: Do you have nested columns ?

Comment: can you add a  screenshot of it ? and if possible to adda screenshot of the dataframe you're trying to write

Comment: yeah it has nested columns. I can't really add the actual schema. But, I can tell there are like 100 or more columns

Comment: btw.. the filter that I'm trying to apply is on the nested column

Comment: `.withColumn("lastFound", functions.date_add(dataFrame.col("last_found"), -457))` is that not a filter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198435/discussion-between-datajanitor-and-firsni).

Comment: no it's not. it just replaces the lastFound column with a new one